# how to replace all the periods after the first of a string with the javascript replace function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, replace

Hello I am trying through (replace) to omit the entry of letters and semicolons at the beginning and that is already validated but in addition to that I need you not to let me enter a second period once it has already been entered, I hope you can help me:

my code:
(I am using the onInput method to capture the input)

```
ev.target.value=ev.target.value.replace(/[a-z]|^[,.]/, '').replace('..', '.')
```

ex:

```
111.11         //ok
111.1.1        //x
11.11.11       //x
1.1           //ok
11.11.11.11   //x
```

Comment: Are you trying to block the user from entering a second period? so I can do 1.111111111 but I can do 1.111.111. So if I were to add that second period would you want to return an error or just cut off input? Or do you take in a whole string and just remove all periods after the first?

Comment: Instead of blocking users from inputting certain characters it's often better to just let them, then remind them that the input is invalid once the input loses focus, or the user tries to submit the data. When directly tempering with their input users might think their keyboard is broken or something weird is going on.

Answer (score 3):

You could match what you want to remove, and use a capturing group for what you want to keep.

In the replacement use group 1.

```
^\D*(\d+[.,]?\d*)?.*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\D*` Match any char except a digit that should be removed.
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+[.,]?\d*` Match 1+ digits, optional `,` or `.` and optional digits
- `)?` Close the group and make it optional
- `.*` Match any char that comes after it that should be removed

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/70mT1Z/1)

This way, the input can not contain only a dot or comma as well.

```js
const regex = /^\D*(\d+[.,]?\d*)?.*/;
const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
const updateValue = ev => ev.target.value = ev.target.value.replace(regex, "$1")
input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput">
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this regex:

```js
/[^\d.,]|(?<=[.,].*)[.,]/g
```

Here's an example:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('input', () => {
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[^\d.,]|(?<=[.,].*)[.,]/g, '');
});
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Not sure what's the period for, I assume that's another format of decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function as second argument to [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). I've created a `count` variable which gets incremented for each match found. The first match it is `0` which is a fasly value, after that it will be truthy.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener("change", () => {
  let count = 0;
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[.]/g, (match) => count++ ? '' : match);
});
```

```css
kbd{background-color:#eee;border-radius:3px;border:1px solid #b4b4b4;box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 2px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .7) inset;color:#333;display:inline-block;font-size:0.85em;font-weight:700;line-height:1;padding:2px 4px;white-space:nowrap}
```

```html
<input type="text" /> (press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to fire event)
```